# ArrayList keeps giving me null

Tags: java

I was successful in creating the file and the citizen classes but the ArrayList used to store the citizens is giving me errors. I checked if it was declared and appended properly but if I try to run a method  on the ArrayList data it gives me null in the command line

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class SNIDApp
{

  private SNIDDb sNIDDb;
  private ArrayList<Citizen> data;

  public SNIDApp(String name, char delimiter) throws Exception
  {
    this.sNIDDb = new SNIDDb(name,delimiter);
    String[] cits;
    while(sNIDDb.hasNext())
    {
      try{
      String[] a=sNIDDb.getNext();
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
      char sex= a[0].charAt(0);
      int year=Integer.parseInt(a[1]);
      Citizen cit=new Citizen(sex,year,a[2],a[3],a[4]);
      System.out.println(cit.getName());
      data.add(cit);
      //System.out.println(data.isEmpty());
      }
      catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
      }
    }
  }

  public ArrayList<Citizen> getData() throws Exception
  {
    return this.data;
  }
}
```

Comment: Not a good Question for Stack Overflow. Always do some basic debugging to trace your code before posting here to avoid trivial questions unlikely to help others.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like your ArrayList is never initialized.

Use

```
private ArrayList<Citizen> data = new ArrayList<>();
```